# How to add a label on top of an inputfield in a bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to achieve the following inputfield and a label on top in bootstrap 5. This was achieved in bootstrap 3

[image]

I am trying to add the You send on top of the input field. I have managed to achieve it in bootstrap 3. I cant really make it show well in bootstrap 5 it ends up showing at the wrong section of the form.

```css
.control-label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #5d7079;
}

.forminput {
  display: block;
  height: 72px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #c9cbce;
  padding: calc(4px + var(--size-24, 24px)) 12px 4px;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label class="control-label" for="">You send</label>
  <input type="number" placeholder="1000" name="" value="" class="forminput">
</div>
```

I end up getting

[image]

How can I crack and achieve this in bootstrap 5?

here is a link in [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/RemyMumoh/dp68n9oL/1/)

Comment: Please include an [example]. I added a snippet to your question and as you can see the issue is not able to be replicated.

Comment: Clicked on "Run code snippet" and it looks fine!

Comment: Hi @Zim is the same app in jfiddle [jfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/RemyMumoh/dp68n9oL/1/)

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, this is happening because you are positioning absolutely relative to the viewport, not the wrapping container.  If you make the shared container relative (done easily in Bootstrap 5 by adding a class of `.position-relative`) your absolutely positioned element will position relative to that element rather than the viewport.  So change your `.col-sm-6` to `.col-sm-6 position-relative` and it should work.

Comment: @AlexanderNied thanks a bunch mate